# How do I create a contour map like the one in the attached image? (preferably in Excel, but open to other options)

Tags: excel, contour

I need to create a graph that properly represents the profit-maximizing model of aircraft in different scenarios. I apologize in advance for my lack of understanding in what exactly to call it. As mentioned, I have found the type of graph that would best represent this, but cannot figure out how to code/create it. I have tried using Excel and Think-Cell (and either one of them may work, I just haven't figured out how) and haven't had much luck. The image below represents the ideal graph, linked here:

[image: ![Contour Modelling]]

Does anyone have any idea how to best go about this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: The data I have now looks like this, linked here:

[image]

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: @PeterT See edit - my current data looks like the excel chart under the link "Contour Modelling." It isn't the final data, just placeholder values at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the data to generate a Stacked Column chart.

Here is how I set up my own example data (***before you posted your own data format***):

[image]

Next, select all rows and only the first four columns of the data (42R x 5C) and Insert-->Charts-->2D Column-->Stacked Column. You should get a chart like this:

[image]

Then change the vertical axis options to show Bounds Min=1.0, Max=4.0, Units Major=0.2, Minor=0.1.

[image]

Next, select any of the data series in the chart and format the Series Options for Series Overlap=100%, Gap Width=0%.

[image]

After that, I deleted the Title and Legend, set the Line Style for both Axis to Solid Fill, Black Color. Then I changed the data series colors to be close to your example. Lastly, **make sure the chart is selected** (the border is highlighted with the squares at the corners), then Insert a TextBox over your data and type "B747-200P2F" and manually place it over the correct data area. Repeat this for the other series and you get this:

[image]

Finally, we'll work on the Jet Fuel price line. This series will be added to the chart, then plotted on the **secondary axis** and it's chart type changed to Line.

To start, select only the Jet Fuel price column (F1:F42) and then **copy** that range into the clipboard. Then, make sure the chart is selected and, from the Home ribbon, select Paste Special. Use the default settings, or choose Add cells as New Series, Values (Y) in Columns, check Series Names in First Row, uncheck Categories (X Labels) in First Column, then click OK. (Not much will seem different on the chart yet!)

The next steps are important to take in order (at least for me). Select only the "Jet Fuel Price" series and change the Series Options to Plot on Secondary Axis. Then change the axis options to set the range from 1.0 to 4.0 and set labels to None. Just so we're tracking, here's what I have so far:

[image]

The (almost) final step is to select only the "Jet Fuel Price" series again, then right click it and choose Change Series Chart Type. Make sure you select the Combo chart type and make the selections for each of the series chart types as indicated in this picture:

[image]

Now (finally!) just add another textbox, put in your label and set the text color to red.

[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much! I wasn't expecting such a clear explanation. You are a savior, thank you. I will try my best to replicate that and let you know if I have any other questions.